# It is possible to connect a simple webrtc stream to sip webrtc client?

Tags: sip, webrtc

It is possible to connect a simple webRTC stream with sipjs user stream ?

If I have a simple webRTC application in which simple webrtc stream is connected. So can we make a call between webrtc user stream and sip user stream ?

Comment: The only way to do this is to have some sort of breaker between the two clients. WebRTC streams are encrypted via DTLS-SRTP where the keys are exchanged directly between the two clients. Also, WebRTC SDPs have custom fields that would probably not be recognizable by a SIP client.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin Trent

Answer (score 1):

- SIP is just a signaling protocol

  - nothing prevent you from using SIP as the signaling protocol for your webrtc application
  - you would still need to adapt the transport protocol used by the signaling protocol, likely from WS to TCP/UDP, as browsers cannot open raw TCP/UDP sockets (1)
- the media streams would still be incompatible.

  - SIP uses fixed ip (or user@domain Ids) while webrtc uses ICE to negotiate the addresses/ports/transport protocol used by the media streams. (2)
  - The encryption mechanism are mutually exclusive ( SRTP-DTLS with SHA-256 minimum for webRTC, nothing up to SDES-SRTP for SIP) (3).
  - the codecs are potentially different, and you would also need to transcode (4). There is an overlapping audio codec, but of inferior quality, and there should be soon 264 in common, but it s not yet implemented in the webRTC stack of all browsers.

You need to address at least (1)(2)(3)(4) need to be addressed before you can make a call. Recent versions of freeswitch / kamailio / asterisk implement (1)(2)(3) and are a good base for PoC.

Comment: Hello Alex Thanks for give me the detailed information. Do you know any of the library or example like this ? If yes then please share me.!!!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.pjsip.org/ it has incorporated some ICE functionality. Alex's statement about SIP using fixed IP's and WebRTC using ICE is a bit misleading. Both SIP and WebRTC use SDP to create media sessions (although in SIP's case SDP is not mandated but it's the most common payload). It's generally the RTP stack that will need to do all the heavy lifting as far as ICE and encryption are concerned and pjsip has done some work in this area and there are probably other RTP stacks around with ICE and DTLS support.

Comment: I do not think it's misleading. the SDP INVITE Must contain the sip:ID@IP of the originator, not present with webrtc. SDP 2327 an SDP O/A 3264 states that you should have a global "o=" line which includes the originator IP, not present with webRTC. the webrtc SDP O/A mechanism (JSEP: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-jsep-08) section 3 outlines some of the differences. webrtc2sip.org is a simple example with nice documentation of what needs to be done to bridge both world. There are a lot of js implementations of SIP nowadays: pjsip.org, jssip.net, sipml5.org, sipjs.com.